# How View Model field by another table name based on given ID in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database table called licences and I filter it based on users search criteria

```
 public class LicencesVM
    {
     public decimal ID { get; set; }
     ...
     public decimal Req_ID { get; set; }
     public int L_Type { get; set; }
    public string L_Type_Name { get; set; } // I created this field to carry ACTIVITIES->NAME Field where LicencesVM.L_Type = ACTIVITIES.ID
    ...
    }
```

Repository Search Function that fills LicencesVM with data

```
public LicencesVM[] Search(int? take, int? skip, string FullName, int L_Type, string Hafiza_ID)
            {
                IQueryable<LICENSES> Licences = db.LICENSES;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullName))
                {
                    Licences = Licences.Where(x => x.FULLNAME.Contains(FullName));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(L_Type))
                {
                    decimal L_Type1 = Convert.ToDecimal(L_Type);
                    Licences = Licences.Where(x => x.L_TYPE == L_Type1);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Hafiza_ID))
                {
                    Licences = Licences.Where(x => x.HAFIZA_ID.Contains(Hafiza_ID));
                }
LicencesVM[] LicencesVM_AllQuery = Licences.Select(s => new LicencesVM
            {
                ID = s.ID,
                FullName = s.FULLNAME,
                Hafiza_ID = s.HAFIZA_ID,
                L_Type = s.L_TYPE,
                ShName = s.SHNAME,
                Saq_No = s.SAQ_NO,
                L_Type_Name=db.ACTIVITIES.Select(l=>l.NAME).Where(L_Type == l.ID),
                Sh_ID = s.SH_ID,
                Hii = s.HII,
                Street = s.STREET,
                Lic_ID = s.LIC_ID,
                Lic_Date = s.LIC_DATE,
                Lic_End_Date = s.LIC_END_DATE,
                Sh_Owner = s.SH_OWNER
            }).ToArray();

            return LicencesVM_AllQuery;

        }
```

the ACTIVITIES class needed name

```
public partial class ACTIVITIES
{
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

here's `(Activities) NAME = (LicencesVM ) L_Type`

I want to take the NAME based on `L_Type = db.ACTIVITIES.ID`

this idea surely doesn't work

L_Type_Name=db.ACTIVITIES.Select(l=>l.NAME).Where(L_Type == l.ID)

I want a Linq Query instead of this line of idea

Comment: I tried this

 var d = from a in LicencesVM_AllQuery
                    from b in db.ACTIVITIES.Where(x => x.ID== a.L_Type )
            select new { a.L_Type_Name= b.NAME };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing the query where you fill the LicensesVm[] array you can join with activities, like this:

```
Licenses.Join(db.Activities, l=>l.L_TYPE,a=>a.Id,(l,a)=>new LicenseVM {
    ID=l.Id,
    L_TYPE_Name=a.Name,
    ...
}).ToArray()
```

This is inner join case. If you need outer join should use GroupJoin instead

Comment: Once somebody gives you an answer and it is what you need, you can mark the answer as correct to let other people know that's the answer and give the person who helped you some credits

Comment: ooh yeah thanks too 
but another little question what if there is another (second besides Activities ) table to join ?

Comment: Keep adding .Join as you need. Just do it before executing the query with ToArray

Comment: Licences.Join(db.P_TYPES,l1 => l1.REQ_TYPE , p => p.ID, (l1, p)).Join(db.ACTIVITIES, l => l.L_TYPE, a => a.ID, (l, a) => new LicencesVM{ .. 
gives syntax error with the other table don't know the exact syntax

Comment: Every join needs a result expression (as in my answer) which acts as a Select to let linq know the result of this query. So if you need multiple joins build your intermediate results as anonymous types and in the last join use your viewmodel to fill all fields instead of anonymous

Comment: I understand your idea but the format is the only thing I need plz